# How to check if a perforce file is opened using bash script

Tags: perforce

So I run "p4 opened the_file", it prints the status, but I cannot capture the print:

```
$ a=`p4 opened file1`
file1 - file(s) not opened on this client.
$ echo $a
```

Variable a is empty.

What I want is, I can get hold of the string "`file(s) not opened on this client`" and search for "not opened".

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line to:

```
a=`p4 opened file1 2>&1`.
```

That redirects stderr into stdout, so your variable will capture both normal output and error output.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
p4 -s opened file1
```

all the server output gets sent to stdout and prefixed with a tag saying whether it's "error" or "info" (be careful, it's not always obvious where the distinction is).  For your case that should get you something like:

```
error: file1 - file(s) not opened on this client.
exit: 0
```

Another fun global option (i.e. it goes before the command name, same as the "-s") is "-e", which gives you the raw error dict; you can do interesting things with this like look for a specific error code rather than grepping human-readable message strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ -z "$(p4 -ztag opened $myfile)" ]]; then echo "Not opened"; fi
```

p4 -ztag opened won't return anything for a file that isn't open, so you can just test for empty output.